# Adding a native ios app to an existing Ruby on rails app

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails

I have a working Ruby on rails app.  I would like to add a native iOS app that can get data from eh server and display it.
Anybody knows of a good end to end toturial to create a native ios app that works against a ruby on rails app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something in your question, what you can do is set up all your actions to render json. So what ends up happening is that your iOS app makes a call to the Rails server and the Rails server returns json to the iOS app, where you can then do whatever you want with the data.

## Example

```
def some_action
  @users = User.all

  render :json => @users.to_json
end
```

## Performance of Rendering JSON

[More](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/09/28/lightning-json-in-rails/) on rendering data fast into json.

## Authenticating an User

`For Non-Devise Apps`

One method I've done, and I'm sure there are better, is to send your credentials via a post request to the Rails server. If the user has the correct username and password, then I'll return the user a token that is unique for each user. Then every time the user is doing something with the database and it's important, you send the token from the iOS app as part of the post request to Rails and it validates it for persistent user authentication.

`For Devise Apps`

[TokenAuthenticatable](http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise) is one solution for Devise. You send the token to the iOS app, store it, then when the user is doing something important to the database, you send the token back from the iOS app to Rails. Rails validates the token, then do whatever you want.

Comment: That is helpful, what methods do i use on the iOS side to make the calls and parse json? Also, any idea how i authenticate from the ios against devise?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to write the code on iOS side for parsing json. I imagine it can't be too hard to find. For authentication, I've come up with my homebrew solution. I'll update my answer with more details on that.